# Storing new city weather data and updating existing city weather data in Android SQLITE database

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, openweathermap

I am using [OpenWeatherMap API](http://openweathermap.com/) to extract current weather data in JSON format.

The following data is an example:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-83.05,"lat":42.33},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":48.1,"pressure":1004.19,"humidity":100,"temp_min":48.1,"temp_max":48.1,"sea_level":1028.21,"grnd_level":1004.19},"wind":{"speed":15.23,"deg":315.508},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1477154497,"sys":{"message":0.1743,"country":"US","sunrise":1477137281,"sunset":1477175856},"id":4990729,"name":"Detroit","cod":200}
{"coord":{"lon":-87.65,"lat":41.85},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":51.38,"pressure":1009.38,"humidity":100,"temp_min":51.38,"temp_max":51.38,"sea_level":1031.85,"grnd_level":1009.38},"wind":{"speed":8.08,"deg":227.508},"clouds":{"all":48},"dt":1477154834,"sys":{"message":0.1714,"country":"US","sunrise":1477138345,"sunset":1477177000},"id":4887398,"name":"Chicago","cod":200}
{"coord":{"lon":-74.01,"lat":40.71},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":48.14,"pressure":1008,"humidity":100,"temp_min":48.14,"temp_max":48.14,"sea_level":1011.38,"grnd_level":1008},"wind":{"speed":15.46,"deg":296.508},"rain":{"3h":2.2},"clouds":{"all":80},"dt":1477154848,"sys":{"message":0.1842,"country":"US","sunrise":1477134973,"sunset":1477173827},"id":5128581,"name":"New York","cod":200}
```

As "dummy entries" that can be removed at any time the user chooses, these three cities are inserted onCreate() (although now I see why that can be a bad idea)

My intention is to have these three dummy records update onCreate() or onResume() without creating new records of themselves which then are added to ListView.

Adding new cities will pull the current weather data and add it to the table, and subsequently updating with live data.

My idea was to check before insertion if the record already exist, and instead of inserting a new entry, it would find and set the temperature and any other pertinent fields to the new data.

But I am quite clueless and how to begin the "check". Here is my insertion method:

```
 public void insertRow(CustomListData weather){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put("TEMP", weather.getTemperature());
        insertValues.put("CITYNAME", weather.getCity());
        insertValues.put("ZIP", weather.getZip());
        db.insert("weather_data", null, insertValues);
        db.close();
}
```

EDIT:

SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE weather_data(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TEMP VARCHAR(5), CITYNAME VARCHAR(255), ZIP VARCHAR(6) );
```

SECOND EDIT:

[WeatherDataStorage -- helper class](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/99455af27319b58382921f7e4d8bf0e9)

Comment: please post the schema of the "weather_data" table of yours. Then I'll be able to suggest you the appropriate solution based on that.

Comment: The edit has been made.

Comment: As you can see from this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ you need to create an sqlite helper that can perform operations such as read, insert, delete, update etc on a database. When it comes to updating or deleting a record in the tutorial it uses id as the field to identify the row. You need to change this to name so it uses the city name instead.

Comment: Tell me, the records in your table must have ZIP as unique. I suppose you are referring to city ZIP code. IS ZIP CODE UNIQUE FOR ALL RECORDS???

Comment: In the previous scheme it was. I ran into errors due to the same being added onCreate() and I haven't added it again. But I see what you're saying about having a unique zip field

Comment: @Tasos i do have a class that extends the helper. I just posted the insert method and not the entire class. Would it be helpful if I did?

Comment: Thats the Insert, where is the update method ??? yes Paste the whole helper class into your Q

Comment: The edit has been made

Comment: joseph, let me know if my answer helps :) try to follow the logic over there. Even I'm using a similar logic in my app on play store.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if the record does exist in the table, the fastest way to do that would be to check this way(**Assuming the zip code is unique across all records**) :

```
     public static boolean checkIfRecordExists(Context context, String tableName, 
                                String tableAttribute, String attributeValue) {

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(tableName,
            new String[]{"1"},
            tableAttribute + "=?,
            new String[]{attributeValue},
            null);

            boolean recordExists = (cursor !=null && cursor.getCount() > 0);
            cursor.close();

            return recordExists;
     }
```

So you can call this method to check if record exists in your "weather_data" table.

```
public void insertRow(CustomListData weather){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

//(Context context, String tableName, String tableAttribute, String attributeValue) 

    boolean recordExists = checkIfRecordExists(context, "weather_data", "ZIP", weather.getZip());

    if(!recordExists) {
        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put("TEMP", weather.getTemperature());
        insertValues.put("CITYNAME", weather.getCity());
        insertValues.put("ZIP", weather.getZip());
        db.insert("weather_data", null, insertValues);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Try to follow the code carefully. You are trying to check if the record in the table exists with respect to ZIP code.

Hence, when you call the utility method **checkIfRecordExists** with these params checkIfRecordExists(context, "weather_data", "ZIP", "DUMMY_ZIP_1234"),

The query translates to **SELECT 1 FROM weather_data WHERE ZIP = "DUMMY_ZIP_1234"**

You run a select query, save the results in a cursor and check if the cursor holds any records. If cursor holds some records, then it means that the record already exists.

**PS: if the zip code is unique, please use zip code as the primary key**

Comment: What context would I be passing checkIfRecordExist()

Comment: Try this program once in your code. All activities extend Context. I just made a general utility method. If you are using this code inside an activity call this : checkIfRecordExists(this, "weather_data", "ZIP", "DUMMY_ZIP_1234"). This refers to the activity. If you are using a fragment, then use this checkIfRecordExists(getActivity(), "weather_data", "ZIP", "DUMMY_ZIP_1234"),

Comment: If this answer helped you, please upvote the answer and mark it as correct. :)  We do spend a lot of our time on clarifying doubts and posting our answers.

Comment: I was able to implement your suggestions however I am still getting duplicate entries on each new creation of the app